# Transforming FileInputStream into a stream that returns hex

Tags: java, stream, hex, binary-data

I need to supply data from a binary file as a hex string. The current implementation for this loads the entire file into memory, convert it to a hex string and feeds the hex string into another component as a byte array.

The problem I'm now facing is that this file is sometimes very large so I get "OutOfMemoryException". The component also accepts an InputStream as input so I thought I'd wrap my FileInputStream into another stream that returns the file as a hex string.

However I'm not sure how to do this, and while subclassing InputStream seems simple enough, I can see this being very error prone with the different read methods and special cases. It would also be nice if this wheel already exists and I don't have to reinvent it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why are you passing *text* data (a hex *string*) as a byte array in the first place? Can you pass the data chunk-by-chunk? Basically we need to know more about the "other component" here·

Comment: I'm passing the data to a web server that expects the binary data formatted as hex in a post request. I'm currently using a ByteArrayEntity: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ByteArrayEntity.html but I wish to use a InputStreamEntity instead.

Comment: But yes, I could have passed the hex string as a StringEntity instead, but this is not my code.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic idea

```
class HexInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

    HexInputStream(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] buff, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int b = super.read();
        String hex = String.format("%02x", b);
        buff[0 + off] = (byte)hex.charAt(0);
        buff[1 + off] = (byte)hex.charAt(1);
        return 2;
    }
}
```

we create an InputStream

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new HexInputStream(new FileInputStream("1.test")));
```

and pass it to the component. On is.read we always read 1 byte and convert it into 2 hex chars.

It takes some effort to make this idea actually work.

Comment: Thanks, I will adopt this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement this by extending `FilterInputStream` (or `FilterReader`) and overriding the relevant read methods and others that you intended to.  For instance, the `read()` method needs to read a byte, turn it into two hex bytes, return the first one, and hold the second one back for the next `read()` call.

Answer (score 0):

A utility for your problem is provided by Apache Commons IO, which also tries to cover intricate IO scenarios. Here's the link

[hexdump from apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io//apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/HexDump.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: hexdump seems to want the input as a byte array. As my file is large I cannot hold the entire file in memory.